# How do I take a character pointer of 20 characters to output the contents plus the extra whitespace?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, character

This is my first C++ related question and I'm new to character pointers and their usage. I think I've got it down but for an assignment the required output for this program is

[image]

So each first and last name is a character pointer of 20 characters (I could probably size it down but whatever) and when I output it now it looks like 
`cout << stu[i]->first << " " << stu[i]->last << " " << (float)stu[i]->mean << endl;` and outputs the same thing as above but with a single space between each piece of data. How would I get it to print out the whitespace of the rest of the char pointer so it creates nice neat columns?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` when all it is you want to say is `'\n'` (or `"...\n"`). If you want a to flush the stream then be explicit and write `std::flush`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magic whitespace in memory a `char*` points to. If you want to align your output you could use [`std::setw()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    char const *foo{ "Jamie" };
    char const *bar{ "Reynolds" };

    std::cout << std::setw(10) << foo << std::setw(10) << bar << '\n';
}
```

Comment: The OP wants right justification so `std::right` would be appropriate.

Comment: @swordfish Your solution worked! Thank you! I ran it with setw(10) and it matched perfectly on the first run.